# Is it possible to use font that's already downloaded in parent window in child iframe?

Tags: css, iframe, font-face

I think the title is pretty self-explanatory but just to clarify a little more, I'm talking about being able to use the font downloaded in parent window in an `iframe` window. It will be a cross-domain (hence the question).

For e.g.
Let's say I have this in the parent window

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "SomeFontFamily";
  src: url('someLinktoFont.woff')
}
```

So is it possible to refer "SomeFontFamily" in my iFrame window as :

```
p {
  font-family: "SomeFontFamily";
}
```

If not then I can also download the fonts in `iframe` and refer it from there but I was curious if the above is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't.

Each frame (iframe) behaves like a different, encapsulated entity, so if you want to use objects/assets (like images/fonts) you should provide their sources within that frame.

When you use `font-family: "SomeFontFamily";` you expect the frame to know the source of the font by that name, however the current frame is not familiar with that source.

Comment: I noticed that Google fonts use `link` to circumvent this issue. That could be a good workaround for this.

Comment: @shriek, note that even with `link` - the server's response include `access-control-allow-origin:*`

Comment: Yup, just noticed that. Alas, it's not a good workaround as I thought it was.